# How can I add extra params via config.m4 when building a PHP extension?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I am working on a new PHP Extension written in C. Typically the commands I would use to build it look like this:

```
phpize
./configure --enable-framework
make
sudo make install
```

So nothing too crazy here, just standard. My `config.m4` is very basic and looks like this:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(framework, whether to enable framework support,
[ --enable-framework   Enable Framework support])

if test "$PHP_FRAMEWORK" = "yes"; then
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_FRAMEWORK, 1, [Whether you have Framework])
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(framework, framework.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

But I have the `multi.o` binary file generated from gccgo that I want to be part of the compilation process. Adding it just after `framework.c` doesn't work; like it would for a `.c` source file.

Because the `Makefile` is generated automaticly it obviously doesn't know about `multi.o`, so I know it has to be in this `config.m4` file somewhere but I've no idea where.

Does anybody know what I need to do in order for this to work?

Comment: `multi.o` is a source file? Really?

Comment: No sorry that's not a source file, that's the binary gccgo produces. I'll reword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this line to my `config.m4` file and it appears to have fixed it:

```
EXTRA_LDFLAGS=multi.o
```

So now the whole file looks like this:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(framework, whether to enable framework support,
[ --enable-framework   Enable Framework support])

if test "$PHP_FRAMEWORK" = "yes"; then
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_FRAMEWORK, 1, [Whether you have Framework])
    PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(framework, framework.c, $ext_shared)
    EXTRA_LDFLAGS=multi.o
fi
```

Which generates the `Makefile` that has the line `EXTRA_LDFLAGS = multi.o` on line 36. This then pulls in the source I need and works correctly.

Not sure if this is the best / right way of doing it, but it works.